# JPanel doClick() equivalent

Tags: java, swing

Does `JPanel` have a `doClick()` equivalent? I need to call it where the panel is created? I tried calling that and it suggested i casted the panel to an abstract button but then it was impossible to do so.

Comment: No. I assume you panel has a MouseListener, so just invoke the code of the MouseListener.

Comment: [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, `JPanel` does not have a `doClick()` but you can always write your own. Here is an example.

```
private void initPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            doClick();
        }
    });
    doClick();
}

private void doClick() {
    // handle the click
}
```